# create an interface file from a Jar (.class) object

Tags: java, uml, reverse-engineering

I am using a vendor jar file and would like to add some UML diagram references (eclipse Papyrus in particular) from my project classes to methods I use from the vendor.

I'm thinking one way would be to create an interface.java to particular vendor jar classes.

Is there some way to automate the creation of such on interface file?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you can use a java decompiler to get the .java from the particular class, and then Eclipse can extract an interface from the java file for the class. But that might not be directly what you intend.

Comment: Enterprise Architect can (AFAIK) RE a jar file and create a class diagram which contains the interface you're probably after.

Comment: You should probably look into Reverse Engineering options if that tool has any, otherwise there are tools like Visual Paradim, Enterprise Architect, Power Designer and similar that have such capabilities.

Comment: javap worked fine for my needs.  thanks to all